# Getting the full path of an advertised shortcut from outside the MSI

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer, directory-structure, advertised-shortcut, msitransform

I working on getting the full directory path of the key file of a component, of an advertised shortcut using VBScript, from outside an MSI.

I read we can make use of the `MsiGetComponentPath` & `MsiGetShortcutTarget` function. Below is the code that I put together, but I ain't getting the output that I want - that is the path of the key file based on the component column in the shortcut table. Any help is appreciated.

```
Set Installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set Database = Installer.OpenDatabase("C:\StackExchange_Test.msi", 0) 
Set View = Database.OpenView("SELECT `Target`,`Component_` From `Shortcut`")
View.Execute
Set rec = View.Fetch
Do While (rec Is Nothing) = False 
  MsgBox(rec.StringData(1) & " " & rec.StringData(2) & " " & rec.StringData(3) _
    & " " & rec.StringData(4) & " " & rec.StringData(5))
  Path = Installer.ComponentPath (FnMSIFetch("ProductCode"), rec.StringData(2))
  Msgbox (Path)
  Set rec = View.Fetch
Loop

Function FnMSIFetch(varProperty)
  Set Database = Installer.OpenDatabase("C:\StackExchange_Test.msi", 0)
  Dim SQL
  SQL = "SELECT * FROM Property WHERE Property = '" & varProperty & "'"
  Dim View                                  
  Set View = Database.OpenView(SQL)                     
  View.Execute
  Dim Record
  Set Record = View.Fetch
  FnMSIFetch=Record.StringData(2)
End Function
```

Comment: Found this by chance today, for those who find it: [maybe have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63083079/129130).