# Is there way to detect install location without uninstall registry nor C:\Windows\Installer?

Tags: c#, batch-file, installation, windows-installer, batch-processing

Some of the executable that I need to detect is installed properly, but has not written InstallLocation in the usual Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

I also checked C:\Windows\Installer but the GUID was not found with msi file.

Is there any way to know where the files were installed?

Comment: For a specific application?

Comment: Yes for specific application(s).

Comment: `where /r c:\ Applicationname.exe`

Comment: I was hoping that there'd be something written somewhere. Because uninstall seem to know where it is.

Comment: Well, in that case. [this should answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172976/how-does-windows-find-the-installed-location-when-uninstalling-software)

Comment: I am not hiding the application installer. If you are so curious, I am looking for SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework (32-bit) with GUID {007E6B4F-6276-470C-9799-E572E9A8C984} which is under Wow6432Node so yes I am aware of possibility with 32bit. As I stated, the registry for this GUID is visible. But the InstallLocation is not filled in. I checked the App Path but it was not located.

Comment: @Gerhard The answer definitely helped me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

***MSI API***: Here is a sample using VBScript to get the installation path for **`Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86 Minimum Runtime - 11.0.50727`** - update GUIDs for your purpose (obviously):

```vb
Set i = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

' Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86 Minimum Runtime - 11.0.50727
MsgBox i.ComponentPath("{2F73A7B2-E50E-39A6-9ABC-EF89E4C62E36}","{F5CBD6DC-5C9C-430E-83A7-179BA49988CD}")
```

**`Installer.ComponentPath`** method:

- The first parameter is the **product code**.
- The second parameter is the **component code**.

---

***GUIDs***: Open the MSI in question with [Orca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546) (or equivalent, see link) to find the **Product code** in the **`"Property Table"`** and the **Component code** in the **`"Component Table"`**.

---

For installed packages you can do as follows:

- ***ProductCode***: [How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569)
- ***Open Cached MSI***: You can find the cached MSI and do a File => Open in Orca to retrieve the information you need. You can find the cached path using the script below.

***Find Cached MSI***: [The below PowerShell script is from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47208200/129130). It will allow you to find the local cache path for the installed MSI.

```
gwmi -Query "SELECT Name,LocalPackage FROM Win32_Product WHERE IdentifyingNumber='{2F73A7B2-E50E-39A6-9ABC-EF89E4C62E36}'" | Format-Table Name,LocalPackage
```

---

***Links:***

- [Show resolved installation directories for MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60242744/129130)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have seen your other replies related to msi and it has been very helpful.

Comment: Thanks, you are welcome - hope it helped. Yes, MSI is a strange technology - [some very important benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632260/129130) (a bit down the page) and quite a bit of quirks: [common MSI problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840086/how-do-i-avoid-common-design-flaws-in-my-wix-msi-deployment-solution) and [maybe this ad-hoc sprawling one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055861/129130) (section on "anti-patterns").